# Jquery Form Validation Plugin Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to validate a simple Form but the Jquery Validation

Plugin not working when I use only Button not The Submit

Button. 
I can not use the Submit button there Because If I use submit

Button After Submitting the form It take the Action and goes

to Default page while my current form is comes from Ajax. I am

very new to Jquery. Please Help its Urgent...
I am giving the files here. 
index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js">
<script="jquery-validate-min.js">
<script="validation.js>
</head>
<body>
<form id="contact_form">
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><td><input name="name" /></td></tr>
<tr><th>E Mail</th><td><input name="email" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><input type="button" name ="submit" id="form_sub" 

onclick="save"></th><td><input name="email" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the `validation.js` file

```
function save(){

$("#form_sub").click(function(){
$("#contact_form").validate({
'rules':{
'name':{
'required':true,
'minlength':5
},
'email':{
'required':true,
'email':true
}
}
})
}
```

Everything works fine when we use input type="submit"...
But it not working when we use input type="button"

Any Idea how can Fix this?
I am new to Jquery ... Please Help

Comment: You should call the onlick handler using onclick="save()", I think.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you don't need the `onclick`. Remove the `function save()`, `{`, `}`, and the `onclick` parameter.

`.click(...)` in jquery is the same as `onclick`, so you are essentially registering another `onclick` when `save()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I am working this too what I ended up doing was I used submit then on the form I did.

```
Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post , new { id = "myFormid", onSubmit="return false;"})
```

this stops the submit however it doesn't provide the automatic short circuit if the model is invalid.